# When to add seasoning to oven-baked french fries?

Tags: baking, seasoning, french-fries

When baking French fries in the oven, either from a frozen package, or made from cut potatoes, is it better to add seasoning, such as salt, pepper, paprika, etc., before placing the fries in the oven or after? When should one add vinegar or lime juice?

Comment: This is personal preference. Either before or after works, both taste different

Answer (score 8):

Dry seasonings can be added either before or after cooking French Fries. However, for oven-baked potatoes, you want to avoid adding wet seasonings before cooking, as it may impair the crunchiness of the final product.